# Error con Angular-CLI Invalid blueprint: route al ejecutar ng generate route

Tags: angular

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial de angular-cli de angular2 que indica ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
ng generate route dashboard
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto, me retorna el siguiente error:

```
Invalid blueprint: route
```

Hay alguna manera automática de poder generar routes in angular?

Las version de mi angular-cli, cuando ejecuto

```
$ ng version
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
node: 7.2.1
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.8

@angular/compiler: 2.4.8
@angular/core: 2.4.8
@angular/forms: 2.4.8
@angular/http: 2.4.8
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.8
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.8
@angular/router: 3.4.8
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.8

$ ng generate route dashboard
Invalid blueprint: route
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede, esto fue desactivado con la salida del nuevo router hace unos meses y los desarrolladores de angular-cli aun no lo han implementado:

[image: Tabla generadores angular-cli]

Answer (score 1):

Esta función se deshabilitó como dice el KarlosCode en las versiones beta. Sin embargo, ha salido ya la segunda ***Release Candidate*** (la 1.0.0-rc.1) y ya está habilitada de nuevo. Te recomiendo que actualices ya que las versiones futuras no contendrán cambios que puedan romper nada de tu proyecto. Yo ya he actualizado mis proyectos y no he tenido ningún problema.

Aquí puedes encontrar más info sobre como [actualizar](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-rc-update) y sobre los [cambios realizados](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) en Angular CLI.

Comment: Hola @Álvaro Orduna León, sigue el mismo error, actualice la version de angular-c li tanto globalmente como localmente a la @angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1y sigue el mismo mensaje de error "Invalid blueprint: route"

Comment: Actualice en la pregunta el error con la versión de @angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, me he liado y no me he dado cuenta que lo que querías era generar rutas, no un modulo con un router. Según parece, no van a habilitar la opción: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3704